Why are my quotation marks in InDesign italicized?
I am working with a font that uses straight quotation marks. When using the font in InDesign, the quotation marks look italicized.
How the mark should look

How it looks in InDesign


InDesign is using "Typographers Quotes". To turn this off, go to Edit -> Preferences -> Type and uncheck the box that says "Use Typographers Quotes".
